How to filter for IDs where another column value is the same for all rows?
I have the following table in PostgreSQL:
id        fid        val 
--------------------------
200       995        XXLL
200       996        XXLL
201       995        OOOP
201       996        OOOS
202       995        OKIL
202       996        OKIL
203       995        LLLL
203       996        CCCC

I am trying to get all ids with two rows for fid 995 and 996 and  val being the same.
So in the above example, I would like the output of the SQL query to be just 200, 202. For 201 and 203 the values for 995 and 996 are different.

Why does the second column matter? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just check if multiple values per id appear? According to your sample data, this would be enough. If you really need to involve the second column in your logic, please improve the sample data to show why and how this is required.

What's the expected result if an id also has fid 999, having same or different val?

So the expected output is one column and two rows here showing the values 200 and 202. Correct? Or do you want to show the val, too? Or do you even want to show the complete rows, i.e. the four rows for IDs 200 and 202?

@jarlh That's my question as short version ;) And what to do if id 204 only has a 995 row and id 205 only a 996 row and id 206 none of both? The question is really vague.

I should have mentioned - all id's are guaranteed to have both 995 and 996.

To get the best query, you should disclose: exact table definition (CREATE TABLE statement), cardinalities (how many rows? how many distinct values in fid? just 995 & 996?), and always your version of Postgres.

Based on your sample data
SELECT X.ID,X.fid,X.val
FROM your_table AS X
JOIN
(
  SELECT C.ID
  FROM your_table AS C
  GROUP BY C.id
  HAVING MIN(C.VAL)=MAX(C.VAL)
)SQ ON X.id=SQ.id


Something like this:
SELECT qr2.id FROM
(SELECT id, val, count(1)
FROM table_1
GROUP BY id, val
HAVING count(1) > 1) qr1
JOIN
(SELECT id, fid
FROM table_1) qr2
ON qr1.id = qr2.id
GROUP BY qr2.id
ORDER BY qr2.id;


You can use INTERSECT to find rows having same val for an id.
select id from
(
  select id, val from tablename where fid = 995
  intersect
  select id, val from tablename where fid = 996
) dt

Or, simply do a GROUP BY:
select id
from tablename
where fid in (995, 996)
group by id
having count(distinct val) = 1

   and count(distinct fid) = 2; -- add to verify both 995 and 996 are there

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/48yG7aBK

The best answer depends on undisclosed details.
If we can assume a PRIMARY KEY constraint on (id, fid), or at least a UNIQUE index / constraint and both columns NOT NULL, or created with NULLS NOT DISTINCT - see:

Create unique constraint with null columns

SELECT id
FROM   tbl
WHERE  fid IN (995, 996)  -- only if there can be other fid
GROUP  BY id, val   -- !!
HAVING count(*) = 2
ORDER  BY id;  -- optional

fiddle
The key ingredient is GROUP  BY id, val.
Even works for val IS NULL (treating null values as equal).
In Postgres, count(*) is faster than count(1) or count(fid), and much faster than count(DISTINCT fid).
Aside: if there is always a row for each 995 and 996, consider separate columns val_995 and val_996. Simpler, smaller table, faster.
